# What is the best way to setup a git server[using gitlab] where the repository is under public_html?

Tags: git, gitlab

I want a way to setup a git server using gitlab on our development server so that when someone commits code it commits to the working copy under public_html.

I have looked at instances of using git inside public_html as a git client and pull from the same machine using cron. However this is not ideal and will not work for us.

What I have found so far is to change git_data_dir "/mnt/nas/git-data" in /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb . But then the whole directory structure is copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please understand that the repositories you push to (in gitlab and other hosted git servers) are bare repositories - they don't have a working copy. Thats why the normal workflow is to have a separate clone/working copy that gets updated on a commit.

Git repositories support [hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks) which you can use to perform a "git pull" in your `public_html`. That should get you settled. If no, please explain why "this is not ideal and will not owrk for us".

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to do this without using a hook. I want to keep the ability for people to ftp code in initially till things settle down and everyone starts using git. So I could see potential conflicts happening on the dev environment in what ever way I think of implementing this. So is there any tried and tested way of doing this "right".

Comment: FTP uploading where to? The public_html folder or the git repo? If you want the git repo, the system would need to support to make commits out of this the git users etc can see their changes. There is a whole lot more stuff that you need to think about.